# Mediaplayer array как создать?

Tags: java, android, массивы, mediaplayer

MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.do_);

но таких еще 30 строк.. как их можно взять в массив?

Comment: А для какой цели вам это нужно? Может просто использовать один, но менять песни?

Comment: бро создал и все работает, но есть одна проблема ща скажу

Comment: я создаю пианино, у меня есть 16 нот, ну 16 аудио файлов)) каждая нота длится 1 секунд..  у меня проблема такова.. если сразу нажать на двух клавиш, то оно не играет ноты одновременно, а поочередно... а если побыстрее нажать несколько раз, то краш происходит))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для вашей цели лучше подойдет класс [SoundPool](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/239-urok-127-media-soundpool.html). Он как раз предназначен, для  многократного воспроизведения небольших файлов.

Comment: Что делано, то делано)) уже отправил работодателю)) эх жиза... ладно, в следующий раз буду использовать Soundpool

Comment: вчера все эти краши пофиксил, так норм работает, но буду уже использовать SoundPool)) ладно, спс бро

Comment: Пожалуйста. Подтвердите галочкой ответ, если он вам помог.

Comment: Все отметил)) спасибо вам